# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0'

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using Spring 3.0.5 and Quartz 1.8.3 and I am getting exceptions in SchedulerFactoryBean
Can someone help me with this? with Quartz 1.8.6 also its not working

I have following configuration

```
<bean name="dailyScheduleBean" class="com.abc.quartz.ComputeAndScheduleAlert" />


<bean id="dailyQuartzJob"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="dailyScheduleBean" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="computeScheduleAlert" />
</bean>

<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
<!-- see the example of method invoking job above -->
<property name="jobDetail" ref="dailyQuartzJob" />
<!-- 10 seconds -->
<property name="startDelay" value="10000" />
<!-- repeat every 50 seconds -->
<property name="repeatInterval" value="50000" />
</bean>

<bean id="dailyTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="dailyQuartzJob" />
    <!-- run every morning at 00:05 AM CST -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 05 11 ? JAN-DEC SUN-SAT" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>          
            <ref bean="dailyTrigger" />                 
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger" /> 
        </list>
    </property>
```

Following is Full Stack Trace

```
%[main] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Context initialization failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hmpn-mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR. [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.]]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4420)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR. [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.]]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.initialize(JobStoreSupport.java:607)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.initialize(JobStoreCMT.java:142)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore.initialize(LocalDataSourceJobStore.java:151)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1269)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.createScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:600)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR. [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:109)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DBSemaphore.obtainLock(DBSemaphore.java:112)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3756)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3725)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.cleanVolatileTriggerAndJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:747)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.initialize(JobStoreSupport.java:605)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:632)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:477)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:776)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:89)
    ... 54 more
%[org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-5] DEBUG org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool  - WorkerThread is shut down.
%[org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-8] DEBUG org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool  - WorkerThread is shut down.
%[org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-4] DEBUG org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool  - 
WorkerThread is shut down.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL please add such Quartz Properties to the SchedulerFactoryBean:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL=select lock_name from {0}locks with (updlock,rowlock) where lock_name=?
```